# Why GCC optimizes accessing global array variable

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I have problem with my code as it seems the thinking of gcc is not the same as mine.
Here is simplified version of problem.

```
struct foo
{
    uint16_t var;
};

struct foo foos[7];
struct foo foo;
uint16_t update_visual_alert(uint8_t match)
{
    for(uint8_t i; i < 4;i++)
    {
        uint16_t color = 5;
        if(match)
        {
            color = foos[i].var;
        }
        return color;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

With -01 GCC is cutting of

```
color = foos[i].var;
```

[Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvXkf.png)

But it's working with accessing a single global variable.

```
color = foo.var;
```

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zaVn.png)

Obviously it's not cut without optimization or with volatile keyword, both on color or struct array.
But adding

```
printf("%d",&color);
```

Forces gcc to access them too.
Why does gcc optimize it out?

That is simplified version of the algorithm I'm using in my application and it caused me a bug with ignoring values.

Comment: `for(uint8_t i; i < 4;` = access to uninitialized variable = anything can happen

Comment: Thanks, It looks like thats the root cause. Was so focused on strange behavior I didnt noticed such mistake.

Comment: @BullNuk you are welcome. `gcc -Wall` which includes `-Wuninitialized` is your friend, if for some reason you are not able to compile with warnings you also have an excellent tool: `cppcheck --enable=all .` (despite the name cpp, it also works for C)

Comment: If you're going to use godbolt (which is a good idea), then please include the actual shareable link from its Share button.  Then people can actually try out the code and make their own minor changes, which they can't do with just a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

gcc has simply prevented the UB. Always use -Wall -Wextra as a minimum warning level. With those options gcc generates the warning:

```
<source>: In function 'update_visual_alert':
<source>:14:22: warning: 'i' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
   14 |     for(uint8_t i; i < 4;i++)
      |                    ~~^~~
Compiler returned: 0
```

Without the UB gcc does what you want (using `-O3`):

```
struct foo
{
    uint16_t var;
};

struct foo foos[7];
struct foo foo;
uint16_t update_visual_alert(uint8_t match)
{
    for(uint8_t i; i < 4;i++)
    {
        uint16_t color = 5;
        if(match)
        {
            color = foos[i].var;
        }
        return color;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

```
update_visual_alert:
        mov     eax, 5
        ret
```

```
uint16_t update_visual_alert1(uint8_t match) // no UB
{
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 4;i++)
    {
        uint16_t color = 5;
        if(match)
        {
            color = foos[i].var;
        }
        return color;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

```
update_visual_alert1:
        test    dil, dil
        mov     eax, 5
        cmovne  ax, WORD PTR foos[rip]
        ret
foo:
```

BTW your loop makes no sense at all as it will always take the value of the first element of the array. Also `return 1` will never be reached.

Comment: Actually the loop will always return the value of the 0th element of the array (if `match` is true) because `return color;` will always happen on the first iteration.

Comment: @NateEldredge good spot :)

Comment: I know that it doesn't make sense, I stripped everything for readability :P. And i stripped too much, in real it's void with passing result to another function.
But, yeah I need to stick to -Wall more frequently. It's such an easy bug that I overlooked.